# What Software Development Life-Cycle (SDLC) methodology or methodologies are used by Google?

Tags: google, development-methodologies, sdlc

Does anyone know or have information about which Software Development Life Cycle methodologies are used by Google?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Steve Yegge wrote a long blog post that discussed life at Google including their development methodology:

http://steve-yegge.blogspot.com/2006/09/good-agile-bad-agile_27.html

He notes that

> From a high level, Google's process probably does look like chaos to someone from a more traditional software development company

He goes on to describe working practices, product launches and Google's incentive programs. He concludes with:

> I've outlined, at a very high level,
>   one company's approach to software
>   development that is neither an Agile
>   Methodology, nor a Waterfall cycle,
>   nor yet Cowboy Programming. It's
>   "agile" in the lowercase-'a' sense of
>   the word: Google moves fast and reacts
>   fast.

Comment: *"Steve Yegge wrote a long blog post..."* -- Does he write any other kind? He starts off the post with "*When I was growing up, cholesterol used to be bad for you."* Sheesh. Seriously, though, I love Stevie's rants.

Comment: Yes, the word "long" is probably superfluous for anyone familiar with Mr Yegge! I added it as fair warning in case anyone unfamiliar with him clicked the link.

Comment: That article was written 7 years ago (when Google was roughly half as old as it is now). Does anyone have any information about whether or not things are still as great as that article claims?